# Implement the Entity Framework in the Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am Newbie to ASP.NET, created the MVC Framework Web API which accepts the array of ID's as input parameter and  queries the Oracle DB, this should return the result in the JSON format.Our query is like

```
SELECT STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR AS CATEGORY, 
      STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.SESSION_NUM AS SESSION_NUMBER, 
      Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE) AS SESSION_START_DATE
      from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY 
      where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN(X,Y,Z)
```

where X,Y,Z are the values we will be passing as input parameters

I created the API controller as

```
  public class PDataController : ApiController
   {
    public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
    {
     List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
     string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
     using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
    var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
    var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
    DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
    var strQuery = @"SELECT STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR AS CATEGORY, 
      STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.SESSION_NUM AS SESSION_NUMBER, 
      Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE) AS SESSION_START_DATE          
      from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY 
      where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN(";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strQuery);
     for(int x = 0; x < inconditions.Length; x++)
         {
           sb.Append(":p" + x + ",");
           OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(":p" + x,OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
           p.Value = inconditions[x];
           prms.Add(p);
         }
    if(sb.Length > 0) sb.Length--;
    strQuery = sb.ToString() + ")"; 
    using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn))
      {
       selectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
         using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand))
        {
            DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(selectResults);
            var returnObject = new { data = selectResults };
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
            {
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
            }
             return response;
}}}}}}
```

It works perfectly and returns the result as 
    `{"data":[{"CATEGORY":"Internal Study","SESSION_NUMBER":7,"SESSION_START_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00"}]}`

But would like to implement the entity framework here by using the Model and the DBContext.I created the model class and the DataContext Class as follows

```
namespace PSData.Models
{ public class StudyDataModel
{ [Key]
public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
public int SESSION_NUMBER { get; set; }
public DateTime SESSION_START_DATE { get; set; }
}}
```

And

```
namespace PSData.Models
{
 public class StudyDataContext:DbContext
 {
 public DbSet<StudyDataModel> details { get; set; }
 }}
```

I am not sure how to implement them in the controller. When I tried to create the Controller using `Web API 2 Controller with actions,using Entity Framework` selected both the Model Class and the DB Context Class it creates controller with

```
 private StudyDataContext db = new StudyDataContext();
 // GET: api/StdData
 public IQueryable<StudyDataModel> Getdetails()
```

I am not sure how to proceed as the return type is the `HttpResponseMessage` in my other Controller where I am returning the JSON message. Any help is greatly appreciayed

Comment: You need to create an object of your `StudyDataContext` and then you can access details property. I suggest you spent at-least 30 minutes going through the EF basics tutotials before building big systems.

Comment: @Shyju Yes I created the object as  `private StudyDataContext db = new StudyDataContext()` So I understand if I use `return db.details;` it returns all the keys in the models class. But not sure how will be convertng them in to JSON before returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly convert it to json format. The [content negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) module and media formatter will take care of converting the data to the needed format (XML/JSON) based on the request. By default it returns JSON.

Assuming you have a DTO class like this

```
public class CategoryDto
{
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public int SessionNumber { get; set; }
  public DateTime SessionStartDate { get; set; }
}
```

and in your action method, you can use `Request.CreateResponse` method.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
   var db = new StudyDataContext();
   var data = db.details.Select(x => new CategoryDto { 
                                                    Category = x.Category,
                                                    SessionStartDate  = x.SessionStartDate,
                                                    SessionNumber = x.SessionNumber }
                               ).ToList();
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But rest of the things should be all the same in the Controller right. Like the Oracle Connection, giving the query

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace all that data access code with your EF implemenation

Comment: Yes I want to replace them. So we dont need any of the ` using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn))
      {
       selectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
         using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand))
        {
            DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(selectResults);` May be I am little confused

Comment: No. Just use the method i posted in the answer.

Comment: How does it know the query `SELECT STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR AS CATEGORY, 
      STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.SESSION_NUM AS SESSION_NUMBER, 
      Trunc(STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.START_DATE) AS SESSION_START_DATE
      from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY 
      where STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.STD_REF IN(X,Y,Z)` where will we be giving them

Comment: You can use query `db.details` with Linq. Use `Contains` method for `In`

Comment: Can we give them here in the Code directly instead of using Linq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120757/discussion-between-trx-and-shyju).

Comment: You can loop through each record and filter it, But LINQ gives you short cut methods to do that.  `db.details.Where(g=>new string[] {"a","b"}.Contains(g.Name)).Select(//Existing code from answer`

Comment: Can you give me an example of looping through each record and filter it, I have no experience in the LINQ and not able to proceed with it

Comment: search for `foreach` samples and you will find it. also ,do not ask totally new questions in the comments